# PHP Form with Checkboxes and Dropdown problems when submitting to email

Tags: php, forms, form-submit, checkbox

Ok, I am not very good with php or forms, but have done a lot of digging and come up with no solution that I can figure out how to make work. I have a form with two sets of checkboxes and a dropdown, among the standard name, email, etc... fields. My problem is getting the values for the checkboxes to show up in the email that is received upon form submission. Here is the form code:

```
    <form method="post" action="appointment-process.php">
<fieldset>
    <label for="name">Name<em class="warning">*</em></label>
    <input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="span6" autofocus required placeholder="Raider Red">
    <span class="help-block">Please enter your FIRST and LAST name.</span>

    <label for="email">Email Address<em class="warning">*</em></label>
    <input id="email" name="email" type="email" class="span6" placeholder="raider.red@ttu.edu" required>

    <label for="phone">Phone Number<em class="warning">*</em></label>
    <input id="phone" name="phone" type="tel" class="span6" placeholder="8067421234" required>

    <label for="legal">Legal Issues<em class="warning">*</em></label>
    <input id="legal" name="legal" type="text" class="span6" placeholder="Landlord Problems" required>  

    <label for="classification">Classification</label>
    <div class="controls">                              
        <select id="classification" name="classification">
            <option>Freshman</option>
            <option>Sophomore</option>
            <option>Junior</option>
            <option>Senior</option>
            <option>Other</option>
        </select>                                       
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label for="">Preferred Appointment Times</label>
        <span class="help-block">Please check all of the days and times that work with your schedule</span>
        <div class="controls row">
                <div class="span3">
                    <label class="checkbox" for="timez">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="timez[]" value="9am">9:00 am 
                    </label>
                    <label class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="timez[]" value="10am">10:00 am
                    </label>
                    <label class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="timez[]" value="11am">11:00 am
                    </label>
                    <label class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="timez[]" value="1:30pm">1:30 pm
                    </label>
                    <label class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="timez[]" value="2:30pm">2:30 pm
                    </label>
                    <label class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="timez[]" value="3:30pm">3:30 pm
                    </label>
                </div>                                              
                <div class="span3">
                    <label class="checkbox" for="dayz">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="dayz[]" value="Monday">Monday
                    </label>
                    <label class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="dayz[]" value="Tuesday">Tuesday
                    </label>
                    <label class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="dayz[]" value="Wednesday">Wednesday
                    </label>
                    <label class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="dayz[]" value="Thursday">Thursday
                    </label>
                </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
</fieldset> 
</form>
```

And here is my php code:

```
<?php  
if( isset($_POST) ){  

    //form validation vars  
    $formok = true;  
    $errors = array();  

    //submission data  
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];  
    $date = date('d/m/Y');  
    $time = date('H:i:s');

    //form data
    $name = $_POST['name'] ;
    $email = $_POST['email'] ;
    $phone = $_POST['phone'] ;
    $legal = $_POST['legal'] ;
    $timez = $_POST['timez'] ;
    //$dayz = $_POST['dayz'];

    //form validation to go here....

    //validate name is not empty
    if(empty($name)){
        $formok = false;
        $errors[] = "You have not entered a name";
    }

    //validate email address is not empty
    if(empty($email)){
        $formok = false;
        $errors[] = "You have not entered an email address";
    //validate email address is valid
    }elseif(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $formok = false;
        $errors[] = "You have not entered a valid email address";
    }

    //validate phone number is not empty
    if(empty($phone)){
        $formok = false;
        $errors[] = "You have not entered a phone number";
    }

    //validate legal issue is not empty
    if(empty($legal)){
        $formok = false;
        $errors[] = "You have not entered a legal issue";
    }

    if(isset($_POST['dayz'])){
        $message .= implode(', ', $_POST['dayz']);
    }

    //send email if all is ok
    if($formok){
        $headers = "From: email@email.com" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

        $emailbody = "<p>You have recieved a new Appointment Request.</p>
                      <p><strong>Name: </strong> {$name} </p>
                      <p><strong>Email Address: </strong> {$email} </p>
                      <p><strong>Phone Number: </strong> {$phone} </p>
                      <p><strong>Legal Issue: </strong> {$legal} </p>
                      <p><strong>Classification: </strong> {} </p>
                      <p><strong>Preferred Appointment Day(s): </strong> {$dayz} </p>
                      <p><strong>Preferred APpointment Time(s): </strong> {$timez} </p>                   

                      <p>This message was sent on {$date} at {$time}</p>";

        imap_mail("email@email.com","Title",$emailbody,$headers);
    }

    //what we need to return back to our form
    $returndata = array(
        'posted_form_data' => array(
            'name' => $name,
            'email' => $email,
            'timez' => $timez,
            'dayz' => $dayz
        ),
        'form_ok' => $formok,
        'errors' => $errors
    );


    //if this is not an ajax request
    if(empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) !== 'xmlhttprequest'){

        //set session variables
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['cf_returndata'] = $returndata;

        //redirect back to form
        header('location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

    }


}

?>
```

Any help at all would be really appreciated. This is my first time to post here, so if I didn't follow the right protocol, just let me know and I will correct. Thanks!

Comment: What is the issue? Are the checkboxes not showing up at all? The wrong ones are showing up?

Comment: The values for the checkboxes is not showing up at all in the email that is sent.

Comment: What happens if you do a `var_dump($_REQUEST)` - do the values show up there?

Comment: Sorry andrewsi, but have absolutely no clue where I would need to put that in the code to even try it out. Hate to ask, but can you "spell it out" for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i am guessing that this line:

```
<p><strong>Preferred APpointment Time(s): </strong> {$timez} </p>
```

is just returning Array.

You need to iterate through this array to get the checked ones:

```
$timeAv = array();

foreach($timez as $time) {

    if(!empty($time)) {

        $timeAv[] = $time;

    }
}

$timeStr = implode(', ', $timeAv);
```

this should build up an array of times checked and then add them to a string. I hope i understood correctly - otherwise that is a few lines of code wasted!

Thanks

Comment: For whatever reason, that line isn't turning up anything at all. I will try this out though and see what happens. Really appreciate the help!

Comment: I absolutely may not have done it right, but added the above code and am now getting "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected" pointing to the `if (!empty($time) {` line. MazB, if you don't mind, where was the proper place to add your code?

Comment: There's a typo in that line - it's missing a closing bracket after `$time)`; I'll amend that.

Comment: Its submitting now, but on submission I'm getting the following errors and still no listing in the email.

`Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on line 21

session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at ...php:21) in ...php on line 105

Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at ...php:21) in ...php on line 109`

Comment: check your scripts don't have white space in them before or after the <?php or ?> tags - and check you don't have anything being echo'd out you don't want. sorry for typo - nice one @andrewsi for fixing that :)

Comment: After a little bit more tinkering over the weekend, got it working finally! I'm not sure exactly what I did that made it end up working, but I used both of your suggestions to get me there, so thanks so much MazB and andrewsi. Very much appreciate the help!!